# Let $\{B(t)\,|\,t\geq 0\}$ be standard Brownian Motion. Suppose further $B(8)=0$. Find the probability that $B(4)>1$.

Tags: brownian-motion

Here is my solution, which I am hoping can either be verified or corrected.

$B(t)$ is normal with mean 0 and variance $t$.

$P(B(4)>1\;|\;B(8)=0) = P(B(4)+B(8)>1+0\;|\;B(8)=0) = P(B(12)>1) = P(Z>\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}) = 1-P(Z<0.29) = 1-0.6141 = 0.3859$.

Comment: $B(8)=0$ is null and you are conditioning on a null event...

Comment: Not sure where you are going with that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You cannot condition on a null event: if $\mathbb{P}(F)=0$, then $\mathbb{P}(-\mid F)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Interesting. This was a practice question given by my professor.

Comment: By the way, do you have any idea for how I can get more practice with elementary Brownian motion?

Comment: The only equation defining $\mathbb{P}(-\mid F)$ is $\mathbb{P}(E\cap F)=\mathbb{P}(E\mid F)\mathbb{P}(F)$, but if $\mathbb{P}(F)=0$ then $\mathbb{P}(E\cap F)=0$ also, and hence $\mathbb{P}(E\mid F)$ gives you a $0/0$.  If your professor wants a Brownian bridge, he/she should start with $B(t)=W(t)-tW(8)/8$ instead.

Comment: Interesting. I have no idea what a Brownian bridge is, but, your explanation of why the problem is not solvable makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is solvable, but the notation is just some matter of convention. As @user10354138 mentioned, $\{B(8)=0\}$ is a null set, so it certainly isn't "standard" definition of conditional probability, no. It has to do with conditional expectation. Namely, you are to find random variable $\mathbb E[ 1_{\{B(4) > 1\}} | B(8) ] =: \mathbb P(B(4) > 1 | B(8))$. From general theory, the result you'll get will be in form $F(B(8))$ for some borel function $F$. Notation $\mathbb P(B(4) > 1 | B(8) = 0)$ means then value $F(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Because the pair $(B(4),B(8))$ has a joint normal distribution, the (regular) conditional distribution of $B(4)$, given that $B(8) = z$ is normal with mean $z/2$ and variance $2$.

Alternatively, again because $(B(4),B(8))$ has a joint normal distribution, the fact that $B(4)-.5B(8)$ and $B(8)$ are uncorrelated implies that they are independent, and the former has a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $2$. Thus, $B(4) = [B(4)-.5B(8)]+.5B(8)$, conditional on $B(8) = z$ is normal with mean $z/2$ and variance that of $B(4)-.5B(8)$, namely $2$.